# How to add a text field on a jointjs element

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

I am new to Jointjs and Rappid. I have an element (idea_1 in this case), I want to add a note box on the top of it (as shown in the picture below) so that users can store information about the element. anyone who knows how to do it please.

```
joint.shapes.basic.Idea = joint.shapes.basic.Intention.extend({
defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    type: "basic.Idea",
    attrs: {
        ".outer": {
            stroke: 'black',
            fill: '#FAF5AF'
        },
        ".satvalue": {
            transform: "translate(80, 40)"
        },
        ".name": {
            'ref-y': '0.5',
            'text': 'Idea'
        }
    }
}, joint.shapes.basic.Intention.prototype.defaults)
});
```

[image]